# Redirection using API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4

My rails app is consuming an API, for which I auto submit a form and redirect to another website. I am doing it as below:

```
  <%= form_tag "https://www.<somewebsite>.action", method: :post,:protocol => 'https',:id => 'test' do %>  
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'field1', 'value1' %>   
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'field2', 'value2' %>        
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'field3', 'value3' %>    
  <% end %>  
 <script>document.getElementById('test').submit();</script>
```

This works and opens the other website in another window. Is it by any chance possible to call this redirection in an "iframe" so that the url of the other website is masked. I don't want the user to know that he/she is being redirected to another website.

Comment: This sounds fishy and dishonest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's definitely possible and it is invisible to the user.  My company has clients that do this so they can invisibly embed our code in their sites.

You would create your primary page with an `iframe` inside it.  When your primary page loads the `iframe` would point to your own page page that contains just your form from the code above:

```
<iframe src="your_page_with_the_form.html" name="my_iframe" width="300" height="1200"  frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" style="background-color:#F7F3DE;"></iframe>
```

Adjust the `iframe` `height` and `width` accordingly.  You then create your_page_with_the_form.html and put your `form_tag` code into it.

If your code causes the submission to "pop out" of the `iframe` then you may need to specify `:target => 'my_iframe'` in your `form_tag`.

An alternative method would be to keep your form on your primary page and use Javascript to send your form data to the external API.

Comment: Users can set browsers to block iframe content.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if and only if `somewebsite` has not set the [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) header correctly.